# How to accept donations?

Tags: paypal, donation

(I know it's a duplicate question but the other answers are old and links are not working anymore)

I need to accept BTC donations from my GitHub page, and I was wondering how to do it.

I've created an address with Bitcoin Knots to receive payments, but from what I'm seeing the address will stop working after receiving the first donation, meaning that I should create a new one for each donation.

Of course this can't be done manually, so here are my questions:

- Does the address really stop working after receiving one payment?
- If yes, how can I automatically generate new addresses everytime?
- (bonus) Is there a trusted way to move my BTC to a PayPal account?

Comment: It doesn't need to be overly complex. You can just paste in your bitcoin address and that's it.  You can take it slightly further and add a QR code, but there's no need to involve a third party service here.

Answer (score 2):

Addresses are intended to be used once, and there are problems with reuse, but it is usually safe to just use the same one repeatedly for donations if you don't have a way to update it easily. However, Bitcoin is still a new technology, so this may change in the future (making reuse stop working) - read the release notes of new versions before you upgrade to ensure you're not caught by surprise.

If you have a way to update the webpage automatically, there is a JSON-RPC method "getnewaddress" that you can use. However, it is very unsafe to run your Bitcoin wallet on a webserver, so be sure if you go this route that you push it from a separate, secured machine.

PayPal does not at this time support Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SpectroCoin wallet](https://spectrocoin.com/en/bitcoin-wallet.html) to received donations, it could also solve your issue with PayPal as you can link your [SpectroCoin debit card](https://spectrocoin.com/en/bitcoin-debit-card.html) to your PayPal account and easily transfer funds to it.